# grep a range of unix timestamps from a logfile

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a logfile where every log event has a unix timestamp:

```
1460332800 event a
1460332999 event b
1460342800 event c
1460417039 event d
```

Is there a clever unix-style way to grep all log events within a specific unix time range?

So I want to get all events between `1460333000` and `1460417100` and it would output

```
1460342800 event c
1460417039 event d
```

I don't necessarily need to use grep...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk is good for this sort of thing:

```
awk '$1>=1460333000 && $1 <=1460417100'
```

`$1` is the first field.